# How to parse any xml file generically without knowing the tag names

Tags: xml, linq, xpath

So my method is taking a xmlfile as a parameter (so I wont know the tag names off hand etc...) and append the elements, their values, and if they have any attributes their values as well to labels.Text. I felt like this would be answered already ( tried looking) but most examples on stack overflow are of parsing a particular xml file, which you can do a linq search after XDocument.Load() the file. Another way I noticed is doing a foreach for each element in doc.descendant like so, but this is coming out like a complete mess (and im not even getting the attributes and their values)

```
       XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(TextBox1.Text);

        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants())
        {
            Label1.Text += element.Name + element.Value + "\n";

        }
```

Whats a way to pass in any xml file, and just basically take the element name + their value as well as attribute name + their value.

EDIT: I feel like im getting closer.. heres what I updated so far

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://localhost:56767/File1.xml");
        int i = 0;
        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants())
        {
                var child = element.Elements();
                foreach (XElement node in child)
                {
                    BulletedList1.Items.Add(node.Name.LocalName + ": "+node.Value);
                    if (node.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        foreach (XAttribute attributeNode in node.Attributes())
                        {
                            if (!attributeNode.Name.LocalName.Contains("xm"))
                            {
                                BulletedList1.Items.Add(attributeNode.Name.LocalName + ": " + attributeNode.Value);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
        }
        Label1.Text += i;
```

The only issue I have now is that descendants first few chunks the data for example If I have

```
<Books>
 <Book>
  <Title>title</Title>
  <Author>author</Author>
 <Book>
 <Book>
  <title>title2</Title>
  <Author>author2</Author>
 <Book>
<Books>
```

It starts from the highest level and then works its way down, being all my data is being looped through more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a generic XML document into a generic data structure by using any DOM parser.

It sounds like you want something that's a bit more specific (less generic) than a DOM parser, but not as specific as what you get from (say) data binding technologies. If that's the case, then you'll have to explain exactly what constraints (restrictions from total generality) you want to apply, and exactly what data structure you want to use to represent the result.